# Code coverage for for loop

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have inserted a List of case records with proper values but still, code is not covering as shown above. Can anyone please suggest to me?

Comment: Without seeing your query, there's no way to tell. Presumably, the case query returned no results. P.S. the results of a query are never null. I'm not sure you understand what null means, as even your assertion is written in a way that is meaningless (if it ever failed, the entire platform would be unusable).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can get the record id before you make a DML. Try to collect the record ids after `Database.insert(caseLst);` as below -

```
Database.insert(caseLst);
caseidlist = (new Map<Id,SObject>(caseLst)).keySet();
```

Comment: Hi Vivek caseidlist should be the list. So i have used for loop for caseLst and added cased id's into caseidlist. But still not working. Updated in code. Can you please check

Comment: @Frank - Request you to update the code in ques. Also, put your main class code so that we can have a look to the query.

Comment: Hi Vivek i have updated main class also. Can you please let me know the issue?

Comment: @Frank - Can you confirm the account created in test class has the same record type as in Account_Record_Type_Customer custom label?

Comment: Yes Vivek I checked the label value and recordtypeid assigned in utility class is same.